# issue Adding userid foreign to other tables

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Doctrine is not adding user id column in contacts table. I am using FOSUserBundle.

My Contacts Entity

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

My User Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contacts", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $contacts;
```

I did doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: What are you trying to do? What error message are you having?

Comment: no error message. I get "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata." Which shouldn't happen. There should be user_id column added in contacts table

Comment: What case, from [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), do you want to have?

Comment: One To Many Mapping.I need to be able to make doctrine add a column named user_id in contacts

Comment: If you run `doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql`, can you see it?

Answer (score 0):

My Contact

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

should be

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="contacts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

Missing extra star in doc block